# Error resolving type specified in JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a class with property of type

```
Dictionary<long, List<XmlAttribute>>
```

Iam trying to deserialize this data using below code

```
                    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
                    };
                    scriptMarks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetScriptMarksMsg>(mq.MessageBody, settings);
```

but while execution it is showing below error

Failed to deserialize data. The data may be corrupted. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int64, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Xml.XmlAttribute, System.Xml]], mscorlib]],

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int64, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Xml.XmlAttribute, System.Xml]], mscorlib]]' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Someone has any idea on this?

Comment: can you give an a fuller example including the data or dummy data your working with

Comment: When I try to serialize and then deserialize an object with a `public Dictionary<long, List<XmlAttribute>> Attributes { get; set; }` property, I get a very different exception: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
  Message="XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments"`.  Are you sure you are not getting this exception but then swallowing it somewhere?

Comment: iam not getting this error..